# Rally kanban cards show parent for features

Tags: rally

I have no issues showing the parent for features in my cardboard when the cardboard is only displaying features:

```
cardConfig: {
    xtype: 'rallycard',
    listeners: {
        fieldclick : function(field, card) {
            _loadDetails(card); 
        }
    },
    fields: [
        'Name',
        // 'Parent' - either one of these ways works
        {
            name: 'Parent',
            fetch: ['Parent'],
            renderTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 'Parent: {Parent.Name}')
        }
    ]
},
```

However, when my kanban board is displaying both features and rollups, the parent information does not display on the card.  I have tried conditionally setting it, or using a renderer instead of a renderTpl (the renderer was never called) - I cannot find a way to do this correctly in the API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an App.js code where the Theme cards do not show Parent field, but Feature and Initiative cards do:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', { extend: 'Rally.app.App', componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        var addNewConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
            recordTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Initiative', 'PortfolioItem/Theme'],
            ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'Project'],
            showAddWithDetails: false,
        };

        this.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);
        var myCardConfig = {
               xtype: 'rallycard',
               fields: ['State','Parent']
            }
        var cardBoardConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Initiative', 'PortfolioItem/Theme'],
            attribute: 'InvestmentCategory',
            cardConfig: myCardConfig
        };

        this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is correct.  I had defined the types as `['PortfolioItem']` but when I changed it to `['PortfolioItem/Feature', 'PortfolioItem/Rollup']` then it worked!